# How to order wordpress taxonomy categories depending on their posts view activity(view count)

Tags: wordpress

I displayed the wordpress taxonomy categories with the following code

```
                            $video_args = array(                                        
                            'hide_empty' => true,                                       
                            'fields' => 'all',                                      
                            'hierarchical' => true,                     
                            'orderby' => 'term_order',                                      
                            'child_of' => 0,                                        
                            'get' => '',                                        
                            'name__like' => '',                                     
                            'pad_counts' => false,                                      
                            'taxonomy' => 'video-category',                                     
                            'cache_domain' => 'core'                                
                            );      
                        $v_terms = get_terms('video-category', $video_args);
```

Now I wanted to order categories depending on their inner posts view.For example if in the category Music posts will be viewed mostly it should become the first and etc.How can I do this?

Comment: How do you count your posts views, with a plugin, or you defined a custom meta?

Comment: with custom meta @vard

Comment: if you have a better solution with the plugin no problem tell me

Comment: Custom meta is ok, but you should consider adding a view count meta for the category as well - querying through all the inner posts to get the total views count for each category would be really greedy. A better solution would be to change the view count function to increment the category count as well.

Comment: Can you help me how to add this functionality please?

Comment: Could you share the code you actually use to handle your posts views count meta?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85091/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-vard).

Comment: `  function setPostViews($postID) {

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';

    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

    if($count==''){

        $count = 0;

        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);

        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');

    }else{

        $count++;

        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);

    }

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with a different solution that I first thought with a custom query that will get the `SUM` of posts views for each term. That will make one query per category which is not too much greedy if you don't have too much categories.

First we get your categories (it's your original code, just removed the `orderby` as it is not relevant here):

```
$video_args = array(                                        
    'hide_empty' => true,                                       
    'fields' => 'all',                                      
    'hierarchical' => true,                                                     
    'child_of' => 0,                                        
    'get' => '',                                        
    'name__like' => '',                                     
    'pad_counts' => false,                                      
    'taxonomy' => 'video-category',                                     
    'cache_domain' => 'core'                                
    );      
$v_terms = get_terms('video-category', $video_args);
```

Then we query the total views count for each category - *please note that this is an untested code but should work*:

```
// Query the total post count for each category
global $wpdb;
foreach($v_terms as $key => $term) {
    $count_views = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) AS view_count FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = 'post_views_count'
        AND tt.taxonomy = 'video-category'
        AND tt.term_id = %d
    ", $term->term_id));

    // Add to the category object the result
    $v_terms[$key]->count_views = (!empty($count_views)) ? $count_views[0]->view_count : 0;
}
```

And finally sort the category array by views count:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->count_views == $b->count_views) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->count_views > $b->count_views) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($v_terms, "cmp");
```

Comment: am getting an error Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(),

Comment: Just edited the answer there was an error in a parenthesis placement

Comment: let me try gain ad see

Comment: I tried but not sure if it dislayed correct categories

Comment: it displayed the first which posts didnt viewed

Comment: Updated the sort function to display the most viewed category first.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_INT_CAST, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE

Comment: Remove the `(int)`, will do.

Comment: Yes but now also it is displaying the category which posts didnt viewed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85115/discussion-between-vard-and-anahit-dev).

Comment: Hey @vard now I wanted to display this categories posts with this same order.How can I change the loop for this?Thanks! Want to display category name and underneath its posts